# Update Table View on command from View Controller

Tags: ios, ios7

New to iOS programing and objective-c and am getting stuck on something which I am guessing is simple. Here's my question:

I have a simple, single view application with two text fields, a button and a table view. The idea is that I want to take the text from the two text fields and populate the next available cell in the tableview with this text. I've got everything sorted out except for how to update the contents of the table view on command. Ideally, I'd like the table view to be updated upon pressing the button.

I have a View Controller which is serving as the data source and delegate for the table view.

I am aware of the [tableView reloadData] method, but it requires the appropriate tableView variable within scope. This is fine in say a delegate method like tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and I've gotten it update upon selection of any cell, but what if I want to update the table view when an action unrelated to the table view is performed, say when the button is pressed? There is no tableView variable in scope of this method to call reloadData from (or is there)?

So I guess my question is: is there a way to access the table view variable from the rest of the view controller for the purpose of calling reloadData OR is there a method I'm not aware of that would facilitate this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you you create an outlet for your table view in view controller?
Your view controller will be delegate and data source for the table view (you should set in interface builder or from code:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;

self.tableView.dataSoure = self;
```

I am assuming that self.tableView - is the outlet that I mentioned. When ou have an outlet you can easily update table view after pressing the button: e.g you add new value to an array that is used for filling table view and call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If you do not want to reload all table you can use method insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Actually you have to read next manuals as well:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

This references are really useful.

Comment: Brilliant! Have used outlets so much with buttons and fields but for whatever reason it didn't come to mind that that would work for a table view as well. Cheers!